# How can I get a particular node from SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

My XML is the following: http://api.napiarfolyam.hu/?valuta=eur

I would like to get only the 'vetel' value where the 'bank' is mnb.

My PHP is the following:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://api.napiarfolyam.hu/?valuta=eur") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$vetel = (string) $xml->valuta->bank->vetel;
?>
```

Comment: Iterate over `valuta->item`s and find what you need.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a sample of the XML (rather than just a link, which might change or fail in future) and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should be the solution but the problem is, according to your xml file, bank mnb has no vetel. So the iterator can't see bank mnb.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://api.napiarfolyam.hu/?valuta=eur") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->valuta->item as $item){
    if($item->bank == "mnb"){
      echo $item->vetel;
      break; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, there's no such node in the XML you've provided. The only `<item>` where `<bank>` is equal to "mnb" is as follows, without a `<vetel>` tag.

```
<item>
  <bank>mnb</bank>
  <datum>2016-09-07 11:25:32</datum>
  <penznem>EUR</penznem>
  <kozep>309.3500</kozep>
</item>
```

Using the `kozep` tag as an example though, you can easily use SimpleXML's `xpath()` method to find the matching value, e.g.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://api.napiarfolyam.hu/?valuta=eur');
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo (float) $sxml->xpath('/arfolyamok/deviza/item[bank = "mnb"]/kozep/text()')[0];

// 309.35
```